# Why isn't my my view displaying a width (layout_weight not working)

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to create a 2 column section of a form. It's a pretty straight forward idea but for some reason my layout isn't rendering correctly. I am trying to line up a label on the left and an editText on the right. I know there have been other questions like this on this site but I can't figure out what's missing in my code. It seems like it should be so simple but yet I'm getting nothing. below is my code and a screenshot of what's going on.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use layout_weight="1", not "1dp".

Comment: is there a way to get the heights of the two elements to be equal as well. My width is now good but do I have to "explicitly" give the textView (label) a height to match the EditText which is much taller or is there a better way

Comment: I think you can set them both to layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: yep. That's it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Layout weight takes an integer, not `dp`. You need to apply a weightSum to the parent, in this case, the LinearLayout. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/avoidButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Left"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/followButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Right"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I didn't need to add weightSum but thank you. eliminating the 'dp' was it. So simple but I missed it. I'm new to Android development